# Visual Studio C# if statement not working in Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, visual-studio-debugging

So I have a weird situation, where I get to an if statement while debugging, and I'm finding that even though `EM=="M"`, my if statement `if(EM=="E")` is being entered anyway... I'm also noticing that some of my code seems to be just getting skipped over when I'm stepping though the code(F11).

I'm using C# in VS2015 and VS2017, it's having the issue in both versions. I was using Framework 4.5, I had switched it to 4.6.1 to build a compatible version for a different program. But switching that back didn't change anything...

```
public static string EM = "";
Database db = doc.Database;
    //db.measureunits is 0 or 1
    if (db.measureunits == 1)  // english
    {
      EM = "E";
    }
    else   // metric
    {
      EM = "M";
    }
try
{
  if (EM == "E") //If english
  {  <-- Breakpoint STOPS Here EM is equal to "M" at this point, which shouldn't allow the break point to be hit, since EM("M")!="E"
    topText.TextString = rad + "\" minimum bend radius";
  }
  if (EM == "M") //Metric
  {  <-- Breakpoint never stops Here
    topText.TextString = Convert.ToString(Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(rad)) * 0.3048, 2)) + "\" minimum bend radius";
  }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
      // Extract some information from this exception, and then   
      // throw it to the parent method.  
      if (e.Source != null)
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"IOException source: {0}", e.Source);
      throw;
}
```

If anyone else is aware of this issue or know's what I may be doing wrong, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-building your project?

Comment: Just a wild guess: you have a debugger breakpoint: `EM = "E"` which modifies the value. What you want is `EM == "E"`. At least  older versions of visual studio(2010 for sure, no idea about 2015) accepted it.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have tried rebuilding the project, and just the clean + build. Neither worked. 
@TimSchmelter I have the breakpoints at the beginning curly bracket of each if statement. And the if statements are as typed above. When the debugger stops, it tells me the value of `EM` is M, but enters the first if statement(EM=="E"), even though that is false.

Comment: If it is any help, I suffer this with my MFC projects. It seems to walk the statements first and then goes back and actually performs the proper path of activation.

Comment: @Corey: debugger breakpoints can have conditions, that was my guess

Comment: It is the behavior of debugging code that was built with Release configuration settings.  The compiler does not emit the NOPs that permit setting breakpoints on non-code lines.  Perhaps selected accidentally or built in a different solution.  You'll also want to check if Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" has an affect, it solves a lot of debugger issues.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried the `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` setting, but it didn't fix the issue. Any other suggestions? Sounds like you've run into this issue?

Comment: Sometimes I've had to delete the .suo (Solution User Options) file, it's a hidden file in the same directory as the .sln (Solution File)

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround might be helpful

1. Delete bin and obj folder then re-build.
2. Restart Visual Studio OR PC

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas.

- There occures an exception so that it jumps over the code which is coming after. Press Ctrl + Alt + E and check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Now it should stop at the moment an exception occures and show it to you.
- Your code was optimized during build. Try to build in debug mode or uncheck "optimize code" in the project properties under "Build".
- Delete the obj and bin folders. You already tried this.
- There is something fishy with the PDB file. The PDB file contains information for the debugger. Project properties -> build -> advanced => set "Debug Info:" to "full" (if you use debug configuration this should already be the case) and rebuild the whole solution.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Common Language Runtime Exceptions was already checked. Optimized code was already unchecked. I had tried the deleting of the obj and bin folders. And Debug Info was already set to full.